# How to obtain the updated weights of neurons based on each data in a batch during the training process in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have read the post [How to obtain the gradients in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com) to get gradient in batch_end through Keras' Callback.py .

Here is the code:

```
def get_layer_output_grad(model, inputs, outputs, layer=-1):
    """ Gets gradient a layer output for given inputs and outputs"""
    grads = model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss, model.layers[layer].output)
    symb_inputs = (model._feed_inputs + model._feed_targets + model._feed_sample_weights)
    f = K.function(symb_inputs, grads)
    x, y, sample_weight = model._standardize_user_data(inputs, outputs)
    output_grad = f(x + y + sample_weight)
    return output_grad
output_grad = get_layer_output_grad(model, dummy_in, dummy_out)
```

By referring to this post, I can obtain the neuron gradient of a certain conv2D layer at batch_end. The gradient shape is [32,25,25,20], where 32 is the batch_ Size, 25 is the image size after passing through this layer, and 20 is the filter_size of the previous layer.

But through this post, I can only obtain 1 updated weight value in each batch. Now, I need to obtain the all 32(batch_size) updated weights generated by each piece of data in this batch. Is there any method to obtain it?

By refering the post: [How to obtain the gradients in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com)